# Script still executing in background after stopping

Tags: linux, shell, gnuplot, sh

I'm calculating the **CPU utilization** using the `top` command and simultaneously plotting the output using `gnuplot`.I'm taking the data from `top` command for the CPU Utilization in the `cpu_util.txt` and summing that data into the `data.txt`.

This is my shell script `CPU.sh`

```
write_data(){
    top -b -n 1 |awk 'FNR>7 '| awk '{print $9}'>/home/vivek/project/cpu_util.txt

    a="$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores' | wc -l)"

    awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", (s/'"${a}"')}' /home/vivek/project/cpu_util.txt>>/home/vivek/project/data.txt

    sleep 5 
}

write_file(){
    while :
    do
        write_data
    done
}

plot_data()
{
    gnuplot liveplot.gnu
}


write_data

write_file &
plot_data
```

This is my gnuplot file `liveplot.gnu`

```
set title "CPU utilization"
plot "../data.txt" with lines title 'usage in %'
pause 5
reread
```

As I'm running `write_file` and `plot_data` simultaneously.So when I stop this script, `plot_data` stops but `write_file` executes in the background.
I don't understand why that script is still running, How can I stop `write_file` at the same time when I'm exiting the script.

Comment: You should launch `plot_data` from `write_file` so you can `trap` signals that `plot_data` receives and stop `write_file` also. Take a look about `trap` here: http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php

Answer (score 0):

write a cleanup function and trap the signals. Attach this to the end of the file.

```
function finish {
    pkill -f write_file
    pkill -f plot_data
    exit
}
trap finish SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
```

sighup, sigint and sigterm are used to stop a process. You can other signals as well